# how to validate form inputs

Tags: php, validation

I have two html forms:

1. one for entering new data which I need to do empty field validation also check the input against my table data (duplication).
2. the second is to update a one row of data that was entered by form number one and for this one I need to do name validation "like if name doesn't exists or doesn't match it gives error"

I found some examples online but I didn't understand them 
maybe some on here can help

this is form one code :

```
<form action="http://localhost/wordpress/process.php" method="post" name="myForm">
    Name        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
    Telephone   <input id="telephone" type="text" name="telephone" />
    Fax         <input id="fax" type="text" name="fax" />
    Web address <input id="webaddress" type="text" name="webaddress" />
    State       <input id="state" type="text" name="state" />
    Address     <input id="address" type="text" name="address" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and this is form two :

```
<form action="http://localhost/wordpress/orgupdate.php" method="post" name="myForm">
    <!-- Same Input fields as Form1 -->
    <input type="submit"  name= "submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

thanks

Comment: I understood the 1st part of your question. But didn't get the 2nd part...!!!

Comment: @elavarasanlee I updated it

Comment: So, what all fields U want to make as unique??? And **"like if name doesn't exists or doesn't match it gives error"**: So while updating You want to check the name of an user and then update is it???

Comment: @elavarasanlee for form one I need to make sure name field is not empty and the value should not exists in my table for form 2 I need to make sure that then name field value exists in my table so updates can be done

Comment: So basically your name filed is like user-name and it should be unique. So while updating, you are fetching details from database and displaying in input field right???

Comment: @elavarasanlee my form is for organisation details so one for inserting new org. details into my table and the second is to update the details of that org.

Comment: Ya okie! but for updating, you should keep 2 steps. 1st select an organization to update, 2nd after selecting fetch details from database so that you don't have to worry about checking if name already exists...

Comment: I am going out for a small work, I'll come back here with a working demo.

Comment: you getting me confuse dude....

Comment: Wait U've two different pages rite??? 1 for insert new data and another for update existing data...

Comment: Did get what you wanted???

Comment: @elavarasanlee yes dude I already done with that issue.....but really thanks for the help and sorry as I didn't login here for a while so I didn't see the answer...

Answer (score 1):

I've created a Demo for you which you can check **[here](http://elavarasanlee.in/sof/)**.
**1**. For checking if input field is Empty, I've used following methods:
    a) `required = 'required'` - **Reference**: [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp).
    b) **jQuery**: - fails if Javascript is disabled.

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var name = jQuery.trim($('#name').val());
    if(name == ''){
        $(".err").text('Name can\'t be left empty.');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

c) **PHP**'s `empty($_POST['name']);`.

**2**. To check if Already an org exists with same name, after submitting and validating do,

```
"SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `name` = $_POST['name'];"
```

If number of rows returned is `> 0`, then there's an organization that already exists.

**3**. For updating existing org details, follow two steps:
    I. Provide a list of organization names fetched from db.
    II. Select a name from the list and then edit.
While editing details, I've made name field as `read-only` so that You can use name field in where condition to write update query. But its not a correct method, you should make use of `id` (**Primary key**) to update a particular value.

I've made way for that also, you can achieve that by using `input-type="hidden"` to store the id and when you post the form you can retrieve it and use it in update query.

**Useful Links**:
**1.** [**Demo**](http://elavarasanlee.in/sof/).
**2.** [**Download Source Code**](https://github.com/Elavarasanlee/sof).